# How can I invoke a function whose name is stored in a variable?

Tags: javascript, function

I have a funcion  whose name is stored in a variable , How can I invoke it?

```
var fun_name='foo'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If if function is available in global space

```
window[fun_name]()
```

If is a member of an object then `obj[fun_name]()`

Ex:

```
var obj = {
    foo: function(){}
}
obj[fun_name]()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using.

```
window[fun_name]();
```

Answer (score 1):

it will also have scope, so simply

```
scopeVar[fun_name](args);
```

or if global

```
window[fun_name](args);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "eval" function

This will call alert(3)

```
foo = 'alert(3)';
eval(foo);
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this out.
[How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)

Or simply use a switch like follows:

`switch(fun_name){

case "foo":

foo();

break;

case "foo2":

foo2();

break;

default:

fooDefault();

}`